# Accessing value of a package-protected custom metadata type record from Apex

Tags: apex, managed-package, custom-metadata, 2gp

I have created a package-protected custom metadata type (`sf_Assistant_Settings`), a field (`Value`) and a record (`API_Key`).
I use it to store an API Key which is used when making http requests to an endpoint in Apex (in order to not hard-code it).

I retrieve the value of the custom metadata type record using Apex as follows:

```
public with sharing class Helper {

    public static String getAPIkey() {
        // retrieve the API Key from Package-Protected Custom Metadata Type
        sf_Assistant_Settings__mdt cmdtRecord = sf_Assistant_Settings__mdt.getInstance('API_Key');
        return cmdtRecord.Value__c;
    }
    
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://***';);
    req.setMethod('POST'); 
    req.setHeader('API-Key', getAPIkey());
...
}
```

It works fine when I deploy it to a scratch org, but when I create a package version and want to install the package in a (different) scratch org, it gives the following error (pointing to `getInstance('API_Key')` function):

```bash
Custom Metadata Type cannot be referenced outside code from the same namespace
```

I don't see the reason for this error, because the apex code and the package-protected custom metadata type are both part of the same package.

I tried with namespace prefix as well, but got the same error:

```
myNamespace__sf_Assistant_Settings__mdt cmdtRecord = myNamespace__sf_Assistant_Settings__mdt.getInstance('myNamespace__API_Key');
return cmdtRecord.myNamespace__Value__c;
```

Also tried enabling `Deploy Metadata from Non-Certified Package Versions via Apex` in Apex settings of the target org, but the error persists.

Comment: Is the error during package installation?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava yes.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `getInstance()` doesn't work with package-protected custom metadata types when installing the package. Using SOQL solved the issue:

```
public static String getAPIkey() {
    List<sf_Assistant_Settings__mdt> settings = [
        SELECT Value__c 
        FROM sf_Assistant_Settings__mdt 
        WHERE DeveloperName = 'API_Key'
    ];
    return settings[0].Value__c;
}
```